# Good and afordable Magento hosting solution for small business? Is it possible to setup on a new host with a full Cpanel backup?

Tags: magento-1.9, hosting

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
currently Hostforweb.com
```

We were hacked (or so does the hosting company say), files deleted. I provided the hosting company 6 recent full Cpanel backups as well as seperate backups of the database but they were not able to restore our site saying files must be missing in the backup. We are down for 3 days now and all services in our VPS hosting account seem to be failing - I am unable to access webmail, I have problems in the WHM and cpanel, I get Error messages on a Magento site that was running even after the hack etc.

My friend checked and says we only currently have 4GB of memory on our VPS server (we suppose to have more) and NO swap file setup. 
I opened tickets with Hostforweb for not only the main website restore but also to fix the other service's failures but all they say is:

Our senior techs are working on resolving this as soon as possible and one of them will get back to you in your ticket.

But it never happens (they take about 12 hours to put some note on the ticket and then nothing again).

I even get these warning (lots of them) by Email:

```
[new.horrible.net] FAILED ⛔: lfd (IP address)
[new.horrible.net] FAILED ⛔: cpanel_php_fpm (IP address)
[new.horrible.net] RECOVERED ❇: cpanellogd (IP address)
[new.horrible.net] FAILED ⛔: watchmysql (IP address)
[new.horrible.net] cPanel & WHM update failure in upcp script
[new.horrible.net] FAILED ⛔: cpanellogd (IP address)
[new.horrible.net] FAILED ⛔: lmtp (IP address)
[new.horrible.net] FAILED ⛔: ftpd (IP address)
[new.horrible.net] FAILED ⛔: dnsadmin (IP address)
[new.horrible.net] FAILED ⛔: lfd (IP address)
[new.horrible.net] FAILED ⛔: watchmysql (IP address)
[new.horrible.net] FAILED ⛔: imap (IP address)
[new.horrible.net] cPanel version change from “11.74.0.9” to “11.74.0.9” is blocked
```

I asked their tech on chat if they are going out of business and he replied: "Not that I am aware of, what makes you think that we are ?"

I think I need to find a new hosting company fast. I don't really have the time to look through thousands of hosting companies to find the right one. **Can someone recommend a good affordable Magento hosting solution for an affordable price? I probably need it to be fully managed.**

*Another big question would be if it is possible to use either my full Cpanel backup from Hostforweb or the HTML files only backup plus the database backup to easily setup on the new host? Are there any hosting companies that would offer a free migration maybe?*

Currently we have Magento 1.9.1. Would it be possible to somehow export products and customers and orders out of it and setup on the new Magento 2.x? I would install and configure the Porto theme on the 2.x instalation so pretty much set it up new but keep the products, orders and customer data.

Answer (score 2):

Is your website recovered now? For Affordable Magento hosting you can refer the below link.

https://www.hostingadvice.com/reviews/magento/

Before choosing a hosting plan please finalize your decision whether you are going with Magento 1.9 or Magento 2, because the server requirements will vary for both the versions. You can't buy magento 1 server and host magento 2 application & vice-versa. For Magento 2 it will be rebuild of your existing modules and themes, because the code base is completely different.

Also check with the hosting provider support on free migration of your cpanel backup. Hope this helps you.